# call_user_func_array to not accept unexpected function parameters

Tags: php, function, argument-passing, php-5.5

I have a function which accepts no parameters, i.e. `function doSomething(){...}`.

If I run, `call_user_func_array('doSomething', array('param1' => 'something'));` it doesn't return an error.

Can I make it force an error like, "This function should not accept parameters".

Comment: Sure, just check via [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/function.func-num-args.php) and throw an Exception if needed

Comment: BTW: It is completely irrelevant how you call the function, directly or with `call_user_func()` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to send more parameters to a user-defined function than the function signature defines. That's because you can use additional code within your function to handle these, or simply ignore them.

```
function doSomething(){
    if (func_num_args() > 0) {
        throw new Exception('Too many arguments');
    }
    ....
}
```

Use something like the above to test the arguments that have been passed to your function

Comment: I looked into this, but with a lot of functions it would be great not to have to do it for all all functions. Maybe I could check number of accepted arguments before calling `call_user_func_array`?

Comment: `call_user_func_array('doSomething', array('param1' => 'something'));` isn't conducive to checking the args in the array whenyou're defining the array in the actual call and not beforehand.... but why is it such an issue? If it's your code doing the call, then you control what gets passed to the function

Comment: I want to alert the user that the function does not accept parameters.

Comment: Is this a library that you're writing for others? If so, what's wrong with good documentation identifying the parameter arguments that can be passed, and the fact that any additional parameters will simply be ignored

Comment: Starting with PHP 5.6, I believe, functions can now actually declare explicitly that they take a variable number of arguments, making this stupid hack using `func_get_args()` obsolete. Just wanted to mention this small, related detail.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I suspect you're thinking of [variadics](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php), which doesn't limit the number of arguments in any way, but eliminates the use of func_get_args() by allowing them to be automatically assigned to an array, and which has the added benefit of enforcing a degree of typehinting

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `func_num_args`:

```
function foo()
{
    $n = func_num_args();
    if ($n > 0) {
        echo "Number of arguments: $n, 0 expected.";
    return;
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

:: [Info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) class. Using that, you can detect how many parameters a function expects and avoid calling it on mismatch.